# Why aren't faculty applications peer-reviewed?

Tags: peer-review, faculty-application

Research articles are peer-reviewed. Funding is based on peer-review. Academic dissertations are somehow peer-reviewed (external examiner).

Everything is based on peer-review in academia. I wonder why the faculty applications are not peer-reviewed.

Disclaimer: I know peer-review process is rarely used in some systems, but my question is why it is not as common as letters of recommendation?

Comment: Why would the hiring decision of one entity be subject to the opinions of any other entity? Not everything is based on peer-review in academia, nor should it be.

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean by "peer-review" in this context.  Do you mean why do applicants get to pick their own letter writers instead of the school soliciting letters?

Comment: @JonCuster: You might as well ask why the tenure decisions of one entity should be subject to the opinions of another entity - but they are (external letters).  I think here it comes down to practicalities: the time frames for hiring decisions are too short to solicit external letters.  Tenure decisions are much slower and there is plenty of time.

Comment: In some academic system there are external members in hiring committees and/or external reports are solicited.

Comment: @NateEldredge - yes, input from external peers are requested for tenure decisions, yet tenure committees also have other factors to consider from the perspective of their institution alone. External input on hiring is usually requested as well, but apparently does not meet the definition of "peer-review" in the question. Perhaps we need a clearer definition of "peer-review" in the context of hiring from the OP.

Comment: Aren't faculty applications peer reviewed by the hiring committee?

Comment: I would continue to question the assertion that 'everything is based on peer-review in academia' - teaching assignments, classroom performance, salaries, fringe benefits, faculty club privileges, and any number of other benefits and conditions of employment are not peer-reviewed.

Answer (score 9):

They are.  Applications for faculty positions are typically reviewed by a search committee, which is made up of academics.  This is a form of peer review.

It is true that sometimes the applicant and search committee may be from the same institution when a job application is reviewed, while funding agencies and journals often do not permit that situation.  The reason is that it is not feasible to eliminate all potential conflicts of interest.  In other words, it is hard to obtain external reviewers for something like a search committee.  Also, the members of the search committee know more about their institution's needs than an external reviewer does.

Comment: A "peer" is someone of the same status as you. The committee isn't made up of peers (who would be fellow applicants), they are technically "superior" to you if that means anything. E.g. when you apply for associate professors positions, you're not associate professor yourself, but the committee is usually made up of associate and full professors. Similarly the committee for a full professor position is made up of full professors. (At least that's how it works in France.)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi No, peer review means review by fellow experts.  It does not mean review by academics of the same rank or status.  Peer reviewed journals and funding agencies use peer reviewers who are a different rank from the author (typically at random).